# Como somar coluna de um banco de dados usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Boa noite a todos. Tenho pouca experiência em programação. Peço desculpas se eu não for muito claro na pergunta.

Tenho um banco de dados MySQL (phpmyadmin) com uma tabela de nome "minha_tabela" tendo um dos campos com nome "valor".
Preciso somar o campo "valor" de todas as linhas da tabela.

Para fazer contagem da quantidade de dados funcionou quanto usei o seguinte trecho:

```
$select = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM minha_tabela")->fetchAll();

// atribuindo a quantidade de linhas retornadas
$count = count($select);

// imprimindo o resultado
print $count;
```

Agora preciso fazer a soma e não sei como escrever o programa.
Estou usando programação PDO. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se é só pra saber a contagem, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM minha_tabela` em vez desse `count($select)`, assim você terá uma linha de resultado com o valor. Isso que você fez está trafegando a tabela inteira do MySQL para o PHP só para obter uma contagem, o que é impensável numa aplicação normal (a não ser que você vá usar os dados todos logo em seguida).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a seguinte consulta SQL:

```sql
SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM minha_tabela
```

Veja mais detalhes de como usar o `SUM` [aqui](http://jquerydicas.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/mysql-sum-soma.html).

Daí, no PDO você faz isso:

```
$soma = $pdo->query("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM minha_tabela")->fetchColumn();

// Imprimindo o resultado.
print $soma;
```

Comment: Olá Victor Stafusa. Agradeço muito pela sua resposta. Acabei de testar e funcionou mesmo. Saiba que me ajudou muito. Um grande abraço. e Obrigado a todos que se dedicaram a entender minha questão.

Comment: @JorgePeinado Se minha resposta te serviu, não se esqueça de marcá-la como correta/aceita ao clicar no ✅ verde aqui do lado. Obrigado. :)

Comment: Olá Victor Stafusa. Agradeço muito pela sua resposta. Acabei de testar e funcionou mesmo. Saiba que me ajudou muito. Um grande abraço. e Obrigado a todos que se dedicaram a entender minha questão.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = new PDO("mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$dbname}",$username, $password);
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$soma = $stmt->query("SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM nome_tabela")->fetchColumn();
//imprime com as pontuação e virgula
print number_format($soma, 2, ",",".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$soma = $pdo->query("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM minha_tabela")->fetchColumn();
print number_format($soma, 2, ",",".");
```

Isso salvou uma tarde toda de trabalho!!!!

Obrigado